# Could not integrate google analytics in android app to use Attribution feature

Tags: android, google-analytics, install-referrer, attribution

I want to use google analytics for Install referrer and traffic source attribution for Android App.

I have linked my Firebase project with google analytics. I can see these projects while login in Google analytics.

To integrate google analytics i need *ga_trackingId* that starts with "UA-". I searched for same on google analytics dashboard but could not find it. I also tried to search for measurement id that starts with "G-". But could not fing that too.

I searched for solution on internet but could not find it.

Please help me on this to integration part so that i can use attribution feature of google analytics for android app.

Answer (score 0):

One of the requirements to use Attribution is to link a View.

Views exist for Universal Analytics and not for Google Analytics 4.

The apps (Android/iOS) work with Google Analytics 4 and not with Universal Analytics.

So you can't use Attribution for the app, *currently*.

It is an answer that may not be what you were hoping for but at least you do not waste any more time looking for a solution that currently does not exist.